# Ext.Net MVC refresh Panelgrid from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

In my view have this:

```
@{
 var properties = db.StylesPropertyDefs.OrderBy(o => o.PropertyId);
}

..
..
@(Html.X().GridPanel()
      .Title("Array Grid")
      .ID("propertyGrid")
      .Width(600)
      .Height(350)
      .Store(Html.X().Store()
                 .Model(Html.X().Model()
                            .Fields(
                                new ModelField("PropertyId", ModelFieldType.Int),
                                new ModelField("PropertyName", ModelFieldType.String),
                                new ModelField("PropertyShortName", ModelFieldType.String),
                                new ModelField("PropertyActiveFlag", ModelFieldType.Boolean)
                            )
                 ).DataSource(properties)
..
..
```

And i have an action in the controller to add new property. The new property is added successful but I can refresh the PanelGrid (without refresh the whole page). Here is the controller:

```
    [DirectMethod]
    public ActionResult AddNewProperty(string propertyName, string propertyCode, bool propertyActive)
                {
                    if (propertyName == "" || propertyCode=="")
                    {
                        X.Msg.Show(new MessageBoxConfig
                        {
                            Title = "Error",
                            Message = "The field name or code can not be empty.",
                            Buttons = MessageBox.Button.OK,
                            Icon = MessageBox.Icon.ERROR
                        });
                        return this.Direct();
                    }

    //if all is ok add new property
                    var newOne = new StylesPropertyDef
                        {
                            PropertyActiveFlag = propertyActive,
                            PropertyName = propertyName,
                            PropertyShortName = propertyCode
                        };
                    var db = new TaosKnowledgeDataContext(DataUtils.GetConStringLocal());
                    db.StylesPropertyDefs.InsertOnSubmit(newOne);
                    db.SubmitChanges();

    //reload properties
                    var properties = db.StylesPropertyDefs.OrderBy(o => o.PropertyId);

                    var theGrid = X.GetCmp<GridPanel>("propertyGrid");
//now i need refresh or reload the panel grid.


                    X.GetCmp<Window>("AddNewProperty").Close();
                    return this.Direct();
                    //return RedirectToAction("StyleProperties");
                }
```

So, resuming, I need refresh the PanelGrid datasource(or store) from the controller.
Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solve.
I deleted the Datasource in Store and I put a proxy reader to Controller.

```
.Proxy(
       Html.X().AjaxProxy()
       .Url(Url.Action("Read"))
       .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().Root("data"))
      )
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Read()
        {
            var db = new TaosKnowledgeDataContext(DataUtils.GetConStringLocal());
            var properties = db.StylesPropertyDefs.OrderBy(o => o.PropertyId);
            return this.Store(properties);
        }
```

And when insert new Property:

```
var store = X.GetCmp<Store>("Store1");
store.Reload();
```

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

1. Set up an ID for the Store.

   ```
   .ID("Store1")
   ```
2. Do the following in the controller action.

   ```
   Store store = X.GetCmp<Store>("Store1");
   store.DataSource = db.StylesPropertyDefs.OrderBy(o => o.PropertyId);
   store.DataBind();
   ```

Comment: store = X.GetCmp<Store>("Store1"); give me a null datasource, it is normal? and store.DataBind() give the error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Comment: Yes, sorry, a Store's DataBind call requires a Store's Model which should be recreated manually in such a scenario. Though, your solution with an AjaxProxy is better. Just I was not sure it is appropriate.